# Multi-use Coupon

Tags: magento-1.7, ce-1.7.0.2, catalog-price-rules, coupon

Is it possible to create a Shopping Cart Price rule that will allow a customer to use a coupon code multiple times? For instance, the coupon is good for 3 items per year. The customer could order 3 different times throughout the year and use the same coupon which will track how many times the code has been used.

'Uses per customer' doesn't solve the problem. That setting does not regulate the total number of items that the customer may get for free over a one year period. The only way that setting works is if we set the 'Quantity in cart to 1'. That would force the customer to have to make 3 separate orders and not be able to get more than 3 free items, but I'm sure that is not the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

when you create a shopping cart rule, you can set the `Uses per Customer`, what do you think this is for? :-)

[image]

The problem is, if you allow the customer group `NOT LOGGED IN` to use it, you are lost. This only works if customers have an account. And only if they don't register a new account for each order.

Comment: Of course I understand what 'Uses per customer' is for. However, that does not solve my problem. That setting does not regulate the total number of items that the customer may get for free over a one year period. The only way that setting works is if we set the 'Quantity in cart to 1'. That would force the customer to have to make 3 separate orders and not be able to get more than 3 free items, but I'm sure that is not the best solution.

Comment: ah, got the problem, no I don't think magento can this out of the box